# shell script to run sql query

Tags: shell

can any one please help to create shell script, to connect to Sql and run the specified query and also syntax to connect ftp server.

Thanks in advance
ramana

Comment: one more thing i forgot, I want query result in to .csv file.

Comment: edit the question whatever you want

Comment: show us that you have at least searched here on Stack Overflow. This question gets asked every week. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your database to be oracle.
Read [this](http://dbamac.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/running-sqlplus-and-plsql-commands-from-a-shell-script/) link.

I will just say how to create a csv here:

just modify your sql query:
for eg:

```
select empid,empname.....
```

should be changed to

```
select empid||','||empname....
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following to run SQL queries. I don't know whether it is a standard:

```
    ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0;export ORACLE_HOME
    ORACLE_SID=sidname;export ORACLE_SID
    USERID=usename;export USERID
    USERPASS=`cat path to .pass file`;export USERPASS #/netflow/oracle/.pass

//connect to db as superuser
 su - oracle <<!
/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus -s username/password<<!
    @filename.sql >csvfilename.csv
```